# Como traer variable por medio de GET con PHP orientado a objetos (POO)

Tags: php, poo, get

actualmente yo envio y recibo variables por medio del GET en php estructurado:

```
$fechados=$_GET['fecha2'];
```

Como puedo hacer lo mismo en PHP orientado a objetos (POO)

y de igual forma la impresión de esa misma variable.

Muchas gracias cualquier ayuda me seria de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

    class Usuario{  //Creacion de clase
         private $variable = ""; //Inicalizacion de variables

         public function __construct($variable){ //Constructor
               $this->variable = $variable;
         }        

         public function getVariable(){ //Funcion get
               return $this->variable;
         }
    }

    //Instancia
    $usuario = new Usuario($_GET["variable"]);
    $variableRetornada = $usuario->getVariable();
    echo $variableRetornada;
?>
```

Puedes ver la referencia de este codigo en [How to load php files via $_GET variable OOP way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428643/how-to-load-php-files-via-get-variable-oop-way)